# List all project iterations using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client

Tags: azure-devops

Using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client how can I list all available iterations in my project?

I can connect happily to my VSO instance but I have no idea where to go from there.

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(_collectionUri, _credentials);
ProjectHttpClient projClient = connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectHttpClient>().Result;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to this code to get iterations:

```
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var workItemTracking = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectHttpClient projClient = connection.GetClientAsync<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectHttpClient>().Result;
           var projects= projClient.GetProjects().Result;
            foreach(var p in projects)
            {
                var iteration = workItemTracking.GetClassificationNodeAsync(project: p.Name, structureGroup: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.TreeStructureGroup.Iterations, depth: 5).Result;
                GetIterations(iteration);
            }

 static void GetIterations(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItemClassificationNode currentIteration)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentIteration.Name);
            if(currentIteration.Children!=null)
            {
                foreach (var ci in currentIteration.Children)
                {
                    GetIterations(ci);
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works a treat.  I have found the API documentation which is great if using a basic http client but lacking in documentation for .Net Client.  Do you know if there is better documentation somewhere?

Comment: @SteveBorman Seems there isn't the better document about .Net SDK API, but many articles contain code fragment, so you can search on internet if you have question or problem. If you can't find the solution, you can open a new thread for your issue on stackoverflow or MSDN forum.